# Facebook Messenger Bot - "Subscription service" for bot app

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I would like to know if it is possible to create a Facebook chatbot app and make it open to the public, so that any page that wants the bot's functionality could just "subscribe" the app (as a service).

I know that it is possible to have a chatbot responding to multiple pages, but the app's publisher needs to be an admin of them at the same time to generate the access tokens (more about it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664400/facebook-messenger-platform-setup)) in the app's admin page. That's a problem to the me, as a publisher, since the pages would need to grant admin rights to me and they could not be willing to do so.

So, to recap, what I want to do is:

- Publish the bot to the public;
- Anybody that wants to use it could do that without having to grant admin rights to me.

Thank you (and sorry for the long question, but it was hard to explain).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart#get_page_access_token - pay attention to what it says in the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I guess I'd still need to ask for the "manage_pages" permission for the user, correct? That is not good, since he'd give me access to all of his pages.

Comment: That’s how it works. User have to trust your app, when they grant it permissions.

Comment: yup, thank you. I just wanted to know if there was an alternative approach.